Django template does not exist html pages
I am getting a template does exist error for two HTML pages I have placed the error message below
TTemplateDoesNotExist at /deck/15/
template_folder/create_cards.html
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/deck/15/
Django Version: 4.1.13
Exception Type: TemplateDoesNotExist
Exception Value:
template_folder/create_cards.html
Exception Location: C:\Users\botan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\django\template\loader.py, line 19, in get_template
Raised during:  cardDesigner.views.create_cards
Python Executable:  C:\Users\botan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\python.exe
Python Version: 3.12.2
Python Path:
['C:\Users\botan\Desktop\project\languages',
'C:\Users\botan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\python312.zip',
'C:\Users\botan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\DLLs',
'C:\Users\botan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib',
'C:\Users\botan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312',
'C:\Users\botan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages']
html
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content %}

<div class="container">

  <div class="jumbotron">
    <h1 class="display-3">{{deck.title}}</h1>
    <p class="lead">By {{deck.creator}} in {{deck.subject}}</p>
    <p>{{deck.description}}</p>
    <hr class="my-4">



  <form method="POST">

     {% csrf_token %}
     {{ formset.management_form }}

    {% for form in formset %}
{{form.as_table}}
      <br>
      <hr>
    {% endfor %}

    <br>
    <button type="submit" class="save btn btn-primary">Save deck</button>

  </form>

  </div>

</div>
{% endblock %}


views.py

def create_cards(request, deck_id):
    deck = Deck.objects.get(pk=deck_id)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        formset = CardFormSet(request.POST, instance = deck)
        if formset.is_valid():
            formset.save()
            return redirect('create_cards', deck_id)

    formset = CardFormSet(instance=deck)
    return render(request, "template_folder/create_cards.html", {'formset':formset, 'deck': deck})

in the settings.py file I have also correctly coded the all?
settings.py
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },

